# ASP.NET HttpModule RewritePath virtual directory cache not refreshing

Tags: asp.net, caching, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET IHttpModule implementation designed to rewrite paths for serving files. The module handles only one event, `PostAuthenticateRequest`, as follows:

```
void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("foobar"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("virtdir/image.png");
    }
}
```

The path "virtdir", is a virtual directory child of the application. The application itself runs in a typical location: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IisModuleCacheTest\ The virtual directory "virtdir" is mapped to C:\TestVirtDir\

A request to `http://myserver/iismodulecachetest/foobar` will, as expected, return image.png from the virtual directory. Equally, a request to `http://myserver/iismodulecachetest/virtdir/image.png` will return the same image file.

I then perform the following:

1. Request `http://myserver/iismodulecachetest/foobar`
2. Directly modify C:\testvirtdir\image.png (change its colour in paint and re-save).
3. Repeat.

After anywhere between 1 and 20 repeats spaced a few seconds apart, the image returned will be an out of date copy.

Once upset, the server will only return the current version after an unknown amount of time elapses (from 10 seconds up to a few minutes). If I substitute the URL in step 1 with `http://myserver/iismodulecachetest/virtdir/image.png`, the problem doesn't appear to arise. But strangely enough, after the problem has arisen by using the "foobar" URL, the direct URL *also* starts returning an out of date copy of the image.

**Pertinent Details:**

1. A recycle of the app-pool resolves the issue.
2. Waiting a while resolves the issue.
3. Repeatedly re-saving the file doesn't appear to have an effect. I'd wondered if a "file modified" event was getting lost, but once stuck I can save half a dozen modifications and Iis stil doesn't return a new copy.
4. Disabling cache in web.config made no difference. `<caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />`
5. The fact that this is a virtual directory seems to matter, I could not replicate the issue with image.png being part of the content of the application itself.
6. This is **not** a client-cache, it is definitely the server returning an out of date version. I have verified this by examining request headers, Ctrl+F5 refreshing, even using separate browsers.
7. I've replicated the issue on two machines. Win7 Pro 6.1.7601 SP1 + IIS 7.5.7600.16385 and Server 2008 R2 6.1.7601 SP1 + IIS 7.5.7600.16385.

**Edit - More Details:**

1. Disabling cache and kernel cache at the server level makes no difference.
2. Adding an extension to the URL makes no difference `http://myserver/iismodulecachetest/foobar.png`.
3. Attaching a debugger to IIS shows the `context_PostAuthenticateRequest` event handler is being triggered each time and behaving the same way whether or not the cache is stuck.

**Edit2 - IIS Logs:**

I enabled "Failed Request Tracing" in IIS (interesting how this works for *non*-failed requests also if configured appropriately. The pipeline is identical up until step 17 where the request returning the out of date version clearly shows a cache hit.

The first request looks just fine, with a cache miss:

[image: Good Request]

But once it gets stuck, it repeatedly shows a cache hit:

[image: Bad Request]

The events after the cache hit are, understandably, quite different than the cache miss scenario. It really just looks like IIS is perfectly content to think its file cache is up to date, when it is definitely not! :(

A little further down the stack we see first request:

[image: Good Request 2]

And then subsequent (faulty) cache-hit request:

[image: Bad Request 2]

Also note that the directory is *apparently* monitored, as per `FileDirmoned="true"`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the modified date on the file actually changes?

Comment: Yes, just tested now. Windows Explorer clearly shows a new modification date for the file, but IIS is still returning the old version. The Http header "Last-Modified" is also returning the *old* modification date.

Comment: I would open a support ticket with Microsoft. It's clearly a bug, so it should be 100% free.

Comment: MS support ticket. -sigh- Every time I raise one of those I get another grey hair.

Comment: No kidding, me too. I got my first gray hair 8 years ago, dealing with an ASP.NET memory leak in the virtual path provider implementation.... Got to know the whole ASP.NET team during that fiasco. They patched it pretty quick, though.

Comment: I've the same problem with IIS virtual directory and url rewritten by a HttpModule. Any news from Microsoft? 
thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

```
void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("foobar"))
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("virtdir/image.png?"+randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: In principle I suppose this would subvert the caching and thus bypass the issue, though in practice the instance of `Random` would need to be treated as a singleton to avoid repeating values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the method `RewritePath` to address static resources in a virtual directory.
I do not have a solution for the use of this method but at the end I opted to use the method `Server.TransferRequest` and this shows no caching problems.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(newUrl);
```

The request transfer is processed again by the `IHttpModule` so you need to be careful to not produce loops.