# ASP.NET Web API StreamContent vs IIS Static File handler

Tags: performance, iis, asp.net-web-api, httpmodule

I'm putting together a document-management service using ASP.NET Web API, and performance is of *some* concern.

Based on [this article](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls) by Nathanael Jones, author of the IIS / ASP.NET ImageResizer module, I've developed a few preconceptions on what's necessary for "optimal" performance of serving static files. The precis of that being:

1. Use a `HttpModule` because it's very early in the ASP.NET pipeline (less pipeline = more optimised) and turns out to be easier to deal with this sort of thing than a `HttpHandler`.
2. `Response.WriteFile(filename)` is better than `Response.Write(memBuffer)` where memBuffer is an in-memory C# buffer.
3. A URL rewrite (i.e. `Context.RewritePath(virtualPath)`) is better than `Response.WriteFile(filename)`, because it will use the IIS static file handler, which is well optimised.

Trouble is, thanks to some bizarre caching issue I still can't get to the bottom of ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743458/asp-net-httpmodule-rewritepath-virtual-directory-cache-not-refreshing)), my URL rewrite technique isn't behaving itself.

So now I'm left wondering about a more Web API-centric implementation like the following:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoTheFoo()
{
    return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"");
        response.Headers.Add("content-type", mimeType);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("somefile.doc"));

        return response;
    });
}
```

For a Web API solution this obviously makes things a bit neater, since the file-serving portions of the service can go right alongside the other actions in controllers, but how well is it going to perform and scale? The factors I ponder:

1. **Network bandwidth.** Presumably no difference here, all techniques are writing the same number of bytes.
2. **Speed of writing to the outgoing network stream.** IIS static file handler might be a bit better at this than the ASP.NET pipeline? Maybe less of an issue with integrated pipeline? The service will be serving on anything between a consumer-level couple-of-hundred kbits DSL line, up to a gbit LAN.
3. **RAM usage.** I'm assuming the StreamContent implementation won't be as efficient as IIS static file handler.
4. **CPU usage.** As with RAM, I'm assuming StreamContent is going to be a little more demanding than the IIS static file handler.
5. **Server-side caching.** IIS static file handler offers this (and is precisely what's giving me hassle because it doesn't seem to be behaving itself), but presuming I could get it to behave itself, that's going to offer benefits ahead of the StreamContent implementation. I'm not so worried about this aspect though as the service is more likely to be responding to a lot of *different* file requests, as opposed to the same ones repeatedly.

I'm not in a position to put together a server-farm to test this to get real performance numbers, and I have my doubts that factoring up small-scale test results will give anything accurate. So from those in the know, what sort of differences could I expect? I'm almost ready to abandon the URL rewrite implementation, but if it's going to give me a noticeable performance hit, I'll persevere.

Comment: I would only consider using a Web API/WCF/MVC solution if you placed Varnish in front of it; it's terrible from a RAM and concurrency point of view. ImageResizer's DiskCache is open to non-image data - have you considered just using that?

Comment: Performance improvements from caching (and Varnish, as far as I can tell, is a caching tool) are actually the least of my concerns. As I say above: "the service is more likely to be responding to a lot of different file requests, as opposed to the same ones repeatedly". If there are never any repeat requests, a cache will be ineffective. Furthermore, there are authorisation rules that need to be processed with each request, which I think given the way Varnish works, would cause issues?

Comment: @ComputerLinguist You describe Web API as "terrible" from a RAM and concurrency point of view. But how does it stack up against the alternatives? I'm not talking about the "300 - 1000x" performance gains Varnish is claiming in cached scenarios, cache aside, I'm looking at the raw performance of un-cached requests, as that's where I believe the majority of my services work will lie.

Comment: It's not really about caching, it's about threading models and context switches. If you're just pushing a lot of static bytes from one place to another, the performance bottlenecks are similar to a cache mechanism.

Comment: IIS is much better at sending static content to clients. With WebAPI and MVC, you have to carefully monitor buffering; it's easy for ASP.NET to 'help you' by making 3 in-memory duplicates of the file you're serving - per client. In theory, you should be able to approach 25% of IIS's file serving efficiency in native code, if everything is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are planning to host in Azure, but if you are you can use a dedicated public blob storage container for your images. Then use the CDN service to serve (and cache) the static files for you. This will move the problem off your API and into a CDN, which is designed to handle static resources.

Comment: My intent at question-time was for this to be hosted in IIS, which I don't think is a match for the Azure blob data storage? It's an interesting consideration for a _different_ approach, if not necessarily one that applies to my situation.

Comment: So you would just use blob storage to store the images / static resources. These would be served over HTTP(s) via the CDN service.